# ifelse not working as expected in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to create a vectorial function in R using the command `ifelse` as follows

```
temp <- function(p){
ifelse(p < 0.5 *(1 + 0.5), (1 + 0.5) * qnorm(p/(1 +0.5)), (1 - 0.5) * qnorm((p - 0.5)/(1 - 0.5)))
}
```

The function works well with scalar values, for example

```
> temp(0.1)
[1] -2.251629
> temp(0.9)
[1] 0.4208106
```

but not for vectors:

```
> temp(c(0.1,0.9))
[1] -2.2516289  0.4208106
Warning message:
In qnorm((p - 0.5)/(1 - 0.5)) : NaNs produced
```

The weird thing is that it returns the right answer, but indicating a warning.

What am I doing wrong? It seems that the `ifelse` is evaluating both functions in all the entries of the vector `p`, which is supposed to be avoided with this command.

Comment: What's the warning message? Please provide example input that replicates your issue.

Comment: What is the warning?

Comment: Because when `p == 0.1`, `qnorm((p - 0.5)/(1 - 0.5))` gives an error.

Comment: `ifelse` evaluates both clauses and then subsets and combines them according to the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ifelse` is basically doing this:

```
p<- c(.1,.9)
a<-(1 + 0.5) * qnorm(p/(1 +0.5))
b<- (1 - 0.5) * qnorm((p - 0.5)/(1 - 0.5))
c<-NULL
c[which(p < 0.5 *(1 + 0.5))] <-a[which(p < 0.5 *(1 + 0.5))]
c[which(!(p < 0.5 *(1 + 0.5)))] <-b[which(!(p < 0.5 *(1 + 0.5)))]
```

That is, it creates a vector for 'yes' and a vector for 'no'.  The 'no' vector it creates throws the warning.

The examples in the documentation allude to this.

```
x <- c(6:-4)
sqrt(x)  #- gives warning
sqrt(ifelse(x >= 0, x, NA))  # no warning

## Note: the following also gives the warning !
ifelse(x >= 0, sqrt(x), NA)
```

Comment: Thanks. Then, why this doesn't happen with scalar inputs?

Comment: @JakeJackson : If you look at the first few lines of `ifelse` it is tested if `length(test) == 1` and either "yes" or "no" is evaluated; not both.

Comment: @alexis_laz Many thanks. Then, I will need to either ignore the warning messages, which are harmless in this case, or to evaluate the function entry-wise.

Comment: Also, note that you will not get an warning if the test is always `TRUE` or always `FALSE`, provided `yes` or `no` evaluate without `NA` respectively.  For instance, `temp(c(0.1,0.1))`.  In general, if a function does not use an argument passed to it, it will not evaluate it.