# ifelse not looping over rows as expected

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this:

```
 df <- read.table(tc <- textConnection("
     var1    var2    var3    var4
      1       1       7      NA
      4       4       NA      6
      2       NA      3       NA                
      4       4       4       4              
      1       3       1      1"), header = TRUE); close(tc)
```

I'm trying to create a new column that returns 1 if there's a match or 0 if none.

My non-working code looks like this:

```
 df$var5 = ifelse("1" %in% df$var1,1,
                ifelse("1" %in% df$var2,1,
                      ifelse("1" %in% df$var3,1,
                           ifelse("1" %in% df$var4,1,0))))
```

giving me a table:

```
 var1    var2    var3    var4   var5
      1       1       7      NA      1
      4       4       NA      6      1
      2       NA      3      NA      1         
      4       4       4       4      1        
      1       3      1        1      1
```

The table I actually want should look like

```
    var1    var2    var3    var4   var5
      1       1       7      NA      1
      4       4       NA      6      0
      2       NA      3      NA      0         
      4       4       4       4      0        
      1       3      1        1      1
```

I've looked at the posts:

[ifelse not working as expected in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26012675/ifelse-not-working-as-expected-in-r)

and

[Loop over rows of dataframe applying function with if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518456/loop-over-rows-of-dataframe-applying-function-with-if-statement)

but I couldn't get any answer to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way should be

```
with(df, ifelse(var1 %in% 1,1,
            ifelse(var2 %in% 1,1,
                  ifelse(var3 %in% 1,1,
                       ifelse(var4 %in% 1,1,0)))))
#[1] 1 0 0 0 1
```

---

The reason is that `1 %in% df1$var1` returns only a single element that 1.

```
1 %in% df$var1
#[1] TRUE
```

likewise, in all all the columns, there is 1, so it will return TRUE for all the `ifelse`, resulting in value 1.

whereas the opposite

```
df$var1 %in% 1
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

returns the logical vector with the same `length` as the original column.  In essence, by using `%in%`, the length returned will be based on the `length` of the object in the `lhs` of `%in%`

---

It is not required to have `ifelse`, a better option would be, using `rowSum` on the logical matrix (`df ==1`), and check whether it is not equal to 0, convert to binary with `as.integer`.

```
as.integer(rowSums(df == 1, na.rm =TRUE)!=0)
#[1] 1 0 0 0 1
```

Or another option is `Reduce` with `|`

```
as.integer(Reduce(`|`, lapply(replace(df, is.na(df), 0), `==`, 1)))
#[1] 1 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ifelse` separately for every column you can check row wise if 1 exists in the entire row and then return 1 or 0 accordingly

```
as.numeric(apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x == 1)) %in% TRUE) 
#[1] 1 0 0 0 1
```

Just to explain the steps better:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x == 1))
#[1]  TRUE    NA    NA FALSE  TRUE

apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x == 1)) %in% TRUE
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

as.numeric(apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x == 1)) %in% TRUE)
#[1] 1 0 0 0 1
```